# Ruby on Rails | Get all areas, cities, countries in the world

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, geokit

How could I possibly get a list of all areas, cities,states, countries in the world like Zomato has. Is there any Gem that can help me. I have searched for few GEMS (django-cities, WorldCityLocations) which gives only till cities and not the area.

For example : I want something like Apollo Bunder(area), Mumbai(City), Maharashtra(State), India (country) and also if possible its lattitude and logitude 's.

Comment: Why don't you integrate [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/)?  you can use [google-api-ruby-client gem](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client)

Answer (score 0):

The [Carmen Gem](https://github.com/jim/carmen) will give you Countries and Regions.

For more detail (e.g. Cities and latitude-longitude) you will need to integrate with something dynamic like [Google Places](https://developers.google.com/places/). You might take a look at this [Google Places wrapper gem](https://github.com/qpowell/google_places).